# Laravel validator passing array when null

Tags: laravel

I've got basic laravel validator for my request:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'speciality' => 'required|array|min:1',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response([
            'status' => 'error',
            'error' => 'invalid.credentials',
            'message' => 'error validation'
        ], 400);
    }
```

speciality should be an array, so I define it as `required|array|min:1`

The problem is when my request has an empty array with null inside: `speciality: [ null ]` and this somehow passes my validator.

How can I correct it to catch this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using dot to access the underlying elements/values:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'speciality' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'speciality.*' => 'required' //ensures its not null
]);
```

See the [Validation: Validating Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays) section of the documentation.

---

Notice that `[null]` in not an `empty` array, that's why your initial validation was passed. You can verify this doing:

```php
dd(empty([null]));
```

This will output:

> false

Comment: @gileneusz just to complement, notice that `[null]` in not an empty `array`, that's why your initial validation was passed. You can verify this doing: `dd(empty([null]);`

Comment: @HCK nice catch there. Can you help update the answer with your comment?